# Application deployed with Ant (Migration tool) but would not work

Tags: cloud, salesforce, apex-code

I am developing an application in which i am retrieving records from an object and then want to insert (some of the fields of the) records into different objects. Below is my code in which i cannot figure it out that why my objects are not being populated and new record cannot be seen .

// Scheduler related class 1

```
public with sharing class ScheduleBatchLauncher{
public static String scheduleBatch(Datetime batchTime){
    CreateAndModifyScheduler batchSched = new CreateAndModifyScheduler();
    String cron = '20 25 * * * ?';
    String schedId = System.schedule('Create and Modify Batch 1', cron, batchSched);       
    return schedId;
}
}
```

// Scheduler related class 2

```
global class CreateAndModifyScheduler implements Schedulable{
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
  CreateAndModify scBatch = new CreateAndModify(); 
  database.executebatch(scBatch);
}
}
```

// Batch Apex related class 1

```
global class CreateAndModify implements
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

global CreateAndModifyProcessor processor;
global CreateAndModify(){
        this.processor = new CreateAndModifyProcessor();
    }

global Database.queryLocator start
    (Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Agreement_ID__c, Begining__c,
                                        Contact_Email__c, Contact_Name__c,
                                        Country_Code__c, Currency__c,
                                        Customer_Address__c, Customer_ID__c,
                                        Customer_Name__c,Customer_Postal_Code__c,
                                        Ending__c,Price__c FROM Unprocessed_Agreement__c]);
        }

global void execute(
    Database.BatchableContext BC, 
    List<sObject> listObj){

        list <Account__c> inAcc = new list<Account__c>();

        for (sObject lo : listObj){
            Unprocessed_Agreement__c temp = (Unprocessed_Agreement__c)lo;

            inAcc.add(processor.processAccountRecord(temp));    
            }
        insert(inAcc);
        update(inAcc)
      }

global void finish(
    Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

// Batch Apex related class 2

```
global class CreateAndModifyProcessor {
global Account__c processAccountRecord( Unprocessed_Agreement__c temp){
    Account__c tempAcc = new Account__c();
    tempAcc.Customer_Name__c = temp.Customer_Name__c;
    tempAcc.Customer_Address__c = temp.Customer_Address__c;
    tempAcc.Postal_Code__c = temp.Customer_Postal_Code__c;
    return tempAcc;
}   
}
```

Please if someone can have a look at it. Also, if someone wants to see my build.xml or package.xml please tell..Thank You

Comment: Are you saying that the code was deployed successfully but fails to produce the desired results when executed, or did the deployment with the migration tool fail?

Comment: the deployment with the migration tool seemed to be succesful as the ant deploy command outputs 'Build succesfully'. The monitor deployment page on the salesforce.com also shows the status as completed but the components is zero. So, what i think is that the deployment is succesfull but it fails to produce the desired result when executed..

Comment: It doesn't sound like your classes are being deployed if the Monitor Deployments page is showing 0 components. Are you able to view the classes in your production environment?

Comment: yes, i can. In setup->develop->apex classes. i can see all of my four classes with status 'active' and isvalid 'checked' . It also compiles succesfully. by the ways for writting the code i have used developer console.

Comment: i just read that to deploy succesfully , the test coverage should be atleast 75 %, so could this be the reason for not seeing the desired output??

Comment: Are you sure your scheduled job has actually been scheduled? You can check in Setup -> Monitoring -> Scheduled Jobs. If it is not on the list, you might want to call ScheduleBatchLauncher.scheduleBatch from the developer console. Also, I'm no expert with cron syntax, but it looks like you are trying to schedule the job to run on the 20th second of the 25 minute of every hour. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @LivingThing if you don't have the necessary test coverage the deployment would have failed and you wouldn't be able to see the classes in the production environment.

Comment: i cannot see the scheduled jobs.In which class i should call ScheduleBatchLauncher.scheduleBatch. Yes, i am trying to schedule the job every hour so i can see the results, i just wanted to make it frequent enough so that i do not have to change the value again and again. I have no test cases, and in my setup->develop->apex classes it shows 0% test coverage but it also shows all my four classes and when i compile it compiles...

Comment: If you just want to see the results of running the batch, why not just call `Database.executeBatch(new CreateAndModifyProcessor());` in the developer console? That will execute the batch once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're running a scheduled batch job so every execution is monitored by the system. check setup - administration setup - monitoring - apex jobs for errors.
another debugging option would be using execute anonymous (in eclipse or ui) to execute your job manually and check the logs.